# Docusign, Missed initials: possible to resend the same document?

Tags: php, rest, docusignapi

I send out an envelope and somehow the signer skips an "initials" field. DocuSign shows that the envelope is complete, but I want that initials field completed. Is it possible to resend the same document for just the initials field, so they don't have to redo the entire thing (some 45-50 pages)?

Answer (score 0):

First, it sounds like you envelope had an *Optional* initial tag that should have been *Required*. If this was sent from a template, I would recommend fixing it there to prevent this from happening again. You can confirm this in the web console by selecting Create a Copy from the envelope and reviewing the tag in the new draft that is generated.

There are a few ways to address this. The "correct" way (most robust) would be to clone (Create a Copy), fix the tag in question, resend the envelope and have the signer complete all the tags again.

An alternative would be to:

1. download the completed document
2. start a new envelope from that document
3. place a single initial tag
4. have the signer complete that tag

The concern would be that the metadata from the original envelope would be overwritten in the second. This is possible to do through the API, but if it's for a one-off it's probably not worth the effort to implement.

Comment: It's a PDF generated and sent by our system using anchor tabs. I've had real difficulty finding a relevant example, both in the docs and the SDK. Is this correct?  

$sign_here = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere(['optional'=>false, 'anchor_string' => $args['tab'][0]]);
  $initial_here = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\InitialHere(['optional'=>false, 'anchor_string' => $args['tab'][1]]);

  $signer_tabs = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(
   [
    'sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here],
    'initial_here_tabs' => [$initial_here]
   ]
  );

Comment: Assuming `$args['tab'][1]` maps to the string that appears in the text, yes that looks correct. If it isn't appearing in the envelope, you may need to add the Recipient ID to the tab definition. There's also the parameter `anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent` which can be set to `false` - this will cause the call to fail if the anchor string isn't found, preventing the envelope from being sent in an incomplete state. For reference, the relevant code example would be here: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Controllers/Examples/eSignature/EG002SigningViaEmail.php

Comment: Yep, that's the example I'm working from, however nowhere does it mention "optional" or "required" or similar. Are all signature/initial tabs required by default, or not (it looks like not)? Seems to be a rather large hole in the documentation. We've had two envelopes come back to us with initial tabs empty, and I'm trying to make that not possible?

Comment: @BillinKansasCity - Have you confirmed if the initial tag is being placed at all? You can do so by cloning the envelope and looking at the new draft in the web console. If the tag is missing entirely, you'll need to investigate why. If the tag is present but optional, you'll need to look in to the `required` parameter.

Comment: It's there. What I can't find is where the required parameter is supposed to go, what it's values should be. It's mentioned several times, but not included in any of the examples that I can find.

Comment: apologies, `required` is incorrect - that tag should have `optional` set to `false`. I see in your previous comment, you have `['optional'=>false` in the definition for that tab. If you're still seeing that tag not be required, I'd recommend opening a support case from https://support.docusign.com. Please provide 1) envelope IDs of impacted envelopes 2) an API log from an envelope creation attempt (https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging)